# How to add more fields to the Register form of backpack-laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack

I tried to add more fields to the Register form of backpack-laravel but the Controller is not found.

I followed the documentation: https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/base-how-to#add-one-or-more-fields-to-the-register-form

This is what I wrote into my routes/backpack/custom.php:

```
Route::get('admin/register', 'App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Auth\RegisterController')->name('backpack.auth.register');
```

My Register Controller looks like that:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Auth;

use Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController as BackpackRegisterController;

class RegisterController extends BackpackRegisterController
{
    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param array $data
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        $user_model_fqn = config('backpack.base.user_model_fqn');
        $user = new $user_model_fqn();
        $users_table = $user->getTable();
        $email_validation = backpack_authentication_column() == 'email' ? 'email|' : '';

        return Validator::make($data, [
            'first_name'                       => 'required|max:255',
            'last_name'                        => 'required|max:255',
            backpack_authentication_column()   => 'required|'.$email_validation.'max:255|unique:'.$users_table,
            'password'                         => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param array $data
     *
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        $user_model_fqn = config('backpack.base.user_model_fqn');
        $user = new $user_model_fqn();

        return $user->create([
            'first_name'                       => $data['first_name'],
            'last_name'                        => $data['last_name'],
            backpack_authentication_column()   => $data[backpack_authentication_column()],
            'password'                         => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

I always get the error:

```
 UnexpectedValueException 

  Invalid route action: [App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Auth\RegisterController].

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteAction.php:91
    87|      */
    88|     protected static function makeInvokable($action)
    89|     {
    90|         if (! method_exists($action, '__invoke')) {
  > 91|             throw new UnexpectedValueException("Invalid route action: [{$action}].");
    92|         }
    93| 
    94|         return $action.'@__invoke';
    95|     }

  • `App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Auth\RegisterController` was not found: Controller class `App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Auth\RegisterController` for one of your routes was not found. Are you sure this controller exists and is imported correctly? 

      +8 vendor frames 
  9   routes/backpack/custom.php:8
      Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic("get")

      +11 vendor frames 
  21  [internal]:0
      Illuminate\Foundation\Application::Illuminate\Foundation\{closure}(Object(Backpack\CRUD\BackpackServiceProvider))
```

Has anybody an idea what I can do?

Comment: Can you please try running `composer install` in your project's root directory. Possibly, the new file is not being autoloaded yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Auth\RegisterController;

Route::get('admin/register', [RegisterController::class, 'showRegistrationForm'])->name('backpack.auth.register');
```

to handle the form POST you'll also want to add:

```
Route::post('admin/register', [RegisterController::class, 'register'])->name('backpack.auth.register');
```

This solution is based on an alternative format to create the route here which is documented here:

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing

On that page you can find the following example, which I based my solution on:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;

Route::get('/user', [UserController::class, 'index']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the Say. However, it was necessary to put more things. As shown the code below. So it worked for me.

```php
//routes
Route::group(['middleware' => [config('backpack.base.web_middleware', 'web')]], function () {
    //routes here
    Route::get('admin/register', 'App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('backpack.auth.register');
    Route::post('admin/register', 'App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Auth\RegisterController@register');
});
Route::group([
    'prefix'     => config('backpack.base.route_prefix', 'admin'),
    'middleware' => array_merge(
        (array) config('backpack.base.web_middleware', 'web'),
        (array) config('backpack.base.middleware_key', 'admin')
    ),
    'namespace'  => 'App\Http\Controllers\Admin',
], function () { // custom admin routes
    Route::crud('tag', 'TagCrudController');
    //your codes CRUDs
}); // this should be the absolute last line of this file
```

The controller stood in the folder
App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Auth\RegisterController

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Auth;

use App\Models\Pessoa;
use Backpack\CRUD\app\Library\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;
use Validator;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    protected $data = []; // the information we send to the view

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */
    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $guard = backpack_guard_name();

        $this->middleware("guest:$guard");

        // Where to redirect users after login / registration.
        $this->redirectTo = property_exists($this, 'redirectTo') ? $this->redirectTo
            : config('backpack.base.route_prefix', 'dashboard');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param array $data
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        $user_model_fqn = config('backpack.base.user_model_fqn');
        $user = new $user_model_fqn();
        $users_table = $user->getTable();
        $email_validation = backpack_authentication_column() == 'email' ? 'email|' : '';

        return Validator::make(
            $data,
            [
                'name'                             => 'required|max:100',
                'cpf'                              => 'required|min:11|max:14',
                backpack_authentication_column()   => 'required|' . $email_validation . 'max:255|unique:' . $users_table,
                'password'                         => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
            ],
            [
                'name.required' => 'O nome é obrigatório', // custom message
                'cpf.min' => 'O CPF tem que ter no mínimo 11 caracteres e no máximo 14', // custom message
                'cpf.max' => 'O CPF tem que ter no mínimo 11 caracteres e no máximo 14', // custom message
                'cpf.required' => 'O CPF é obritagorio',
                'email.required' => 'E-mail é obrigatório ',
                'email.unique' => 'O email já foi registrado.',
                'password.confirmed' => 'A confirmação da senha não corresponde.', //password
            ]
        );
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param array $data
     *
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        $user_model_fqn = config('backpack.base.user_model_fqn');
        $user = new $user_model_fqn();

        return $user->create([
            'name'                             => $data['name'],
            'cpf'                              => $data['cpf'],
            'pessoa_id'                        => $data['pessoa_id'],
            backpack_authentication_column()   => $data[backpack_authentication_column()],
            'password'                         => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Show the application registration form.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function showRegistrationForm()
    {
        // if registration is closed, deny access
        if (!config('backpack.base.registration_open')) {
            abort(403, trans('backpack::base.registration_closed'));
        }
        //   $this->data['title'] = trans('backpack::base.register'); // set the page title
        //   $this->data['title'] = "Registrar Usuário"; // set the page title

        return view(backpack_view('auth.register'));
        // return view(backpack_view('auth.register'), $this->data);
    }

    /**
     * Handle a registration request for the application.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        // if registration is closed, deny access
        if (!config('backpack.base.registration_open')) {
            abort(403, trans('backpack::base.registration_closed'));
        }

        $requestData = $request->all();

        $this->validator($requestData)->validate();

        $objPessoa = new Pessoa();
        $objPessoa->nome = $request->name;
        $objPessoa->email = $request->email;
        $objPessoa->cpf = $request->cpf;
        $objPessoa->save();

        $requestData['pessoa_id'] = $objPessoa->id;

        $user = $this->create($requestData);

        event(new Registered($user));
        $this->guard()->login($user);

        return redirect($this->redirectPath());
    }

    /**
     * Get the guard to be used during registration.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard
     */
    protected function guard()
    {
        return backpack_auth();
    }
}
```

And Blande stayed in
resources\views\vendor\backpack\base\auth\register.blade.php

```php
@extends(backpack_view('layouts.plain'))

@section('content')
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-8 col-lg-4">
            <h3 class="text-center mb-4">{{ trans('backpack::base.register') }}</h3>
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <form class="col-md-12 p-t-10" role="form" method="POST"
                        action="{{ route('backpack.auth.register') }}">
                        {!! csrf_field() !!}

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label" for="name">{{ trans('backpack::base.name') }}</label>
                            <div>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}"
                                    name="name" id="name" value="{{ old('name') }}">
                                @if ($errors->has('name'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label" for="name">CPF</label>

                            <div>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('cpf') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}"
                                    name="cpf" id="cpf" value="{{ old('cpf') }}" placeholder="000.000.000-00">
                                @if ($errors->has('cpf'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('cpf') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label"
                                for="{{ backpack_authentication_column() }}">{{ config('backpack.base.authentication_column_name') }}</label>

                            <div>
                                <input type="{{ backpack_authentication_column() == 'email' ? 'email' : 'text' }}"
                                    class="form-control{{ $errors->has(backpack_authentication_column()) ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}"
                                    name="{{ backpack_authentication_column() }}"
                                    id="{{ backpack_authentication_column() }}"
                                    value="{{ old(backpack_authentication_column()) }}">

                                @if ($errors->has(backpack_authentication_column()))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first(backpack_authentication_column()) }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label" for="password">{{ trans('backpack::base.password') }}</label>

                            <div>
                                <input type="password"
                                    class="form-control{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}"
                                    name="password" id="password">

                                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label"
                                for="password_confirmation">{{ trans('backpack::base.confirm_password') }}</label>

                            <div>
                                <input type="password"
                                    class="form-control{{ $errors->has('password_confirmation') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}"
                                    name="password_confirmation" id="password_confirmation">

                                @if ($errors->has('password_confirmation'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password_confirmation') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">
                                    {{ trans('backpack::base.register') }}
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            @if (backpack_users_have_email() && config('backpack.base.setup_password_recovery_routes', true))
                <div class="text-center"><a
                        href="{{ route('backpack.auth.password.reset') }}">{{ trans('backpack::base.forgot_your_password') }}</a>
                </div>
            @endif
            <div class="text-center"><a
                    href="{{ route('backpack.auth.login') }}">{{ trans('backpack::base.login') }}</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```